# @Override problems

Tags: android

In my project, I'm having hundreds of errors because of the keyword `@Override` because I updated my Eclipse, JDK and all the components. This problem is because my team is using older versions. So is there any way I can ignore this error messages? If there is, how? Second option would be to revert back to older version of my jdk. I need some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution to remove your problem,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.

Comment: Happy to Help you Dear. Keep Sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

`@Override` annotation is introduce in JDK 1.5 but here the older version of compiler cannot allow  `@Override` annotation with implemented (`interface`) methods. You either have to remove `@Override` attribute or install (JDK) and change `JDK 1.5` or `1.6` or `higher` from project properties option (Compiler settings).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the Java complier version is set to 1.6 in eclipse for the workspace

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your java version should be 1.6 or later when you have @Override statement, if java version is lesser, you may safely remove @override statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,

I was having a similar problem. I was having the following setup:

Ubuntu Linux 11.10
JAVA 1.6 (which javac returns /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/bin/javac)
eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
android-sdk_r16-linux.tgz
In Android SDK Manager:
  Android SDK Tools 16
  Android SDK Platform-Tools 10
  Android (2.3.3 API 10)
    SDK Platform 10.2
    Google APIs by Google Inc. 10.2

and creating a new Google API android project, but for some reason
despite the installed Java SDK was 1.6 eclipse was still trying to
build a Java SDK 1.5 compatible build, not sure why, I was not
having this problem previously.

Anyway, changing the Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level: 1.6

fixed the problem for me.